# Converge or Diverge? Which test to use?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Hi does this series converge or diverge? We've learnt so many tests and it's all so confusing I don't know which one to use. Can someone start it off for me please

ii)$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\ln \left( \frac{k+2}{k+1} \right)$

Comment: Hint: telescoping

Answer (score 3):

Consider the partial sum $$S_N=\sum_{k=1}^N\ln\left(\frac{k+2}{k+1}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^N\left(\ln(k+2)-\ln(k+1)\right)$$

Comment: $$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty ln({{k+2}\over{k+1}})=\sum_{k=1}^\infty ({ln(k+2)-ln(k+1)})=(ln(3)-ln(2))+(ln(4)-ln(3))+(ln(5)-ln(4))+(ln(6)-ln(5))+...= \lim_{k \to \infty} \ln(k) - \ln(2) = \infty
$$ It's infinity....so I say it diverges. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: That's the right idea. However, to be more precise, you want to write $$S_N=\ln(N+2)-\ln(2)$$ and then take the limit $$\lim_{N\to\infty} S_N=\infty$$ to see the series diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it seem as if there are lots of tests. But you can develop some intuition. There are two basic types of series:

1)Geometric (and similar to geometric !).

2)Harmonic (and similar to harmonic !).

Now the ratio and root tests are useful for series similar to geometric eg
$\sum \frac{n}{2^n}$
 For harmonic or similar you need the comparison with harmonic series. Now your example, is $$\sum \ln(1+\frac{1}{k+1})$$

And if you remember that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln (1+x)}{x}=1$ you see that comparison with the harmonic $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ will tell you the series diverges.

So one should ask of a series if it is similar to a geometric or a harmonic series. (Of course this telescopes, so that is the better way to solve this particular case).